# is there a way to see output of previous ":! g++ %" without rerunning?

Tags: vim

When coding, I like to check the code by running `:! g++ %`. I map the command to `<F5>`. sometimes it takes a while to compile and I want to see the errors without spending time recompiling. Also, sometimes I want to compare the new output to previous one.

Is there a way to see the previous output of `:! ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have `g++` configured with `makeprg`, you can use `:copen` to reopen the last list of errors from the `:make` command.

```
set makeprg=g++\ %
```

Then, to compile, use

```
:make
```

When the compile completes, any errors will be listed in the quickfix window, which can (assuming `errorformat` is correctly configured) be used to jump to the lines on which errors occur.  This usually works out of the box for C/C++.

If you dismiss the quickfix window, retrieve the last error list with

```
:copen
```

Review `:help quickfix` and `:help makeprg` for full gory details on how this works.

Comment: Use `:colder` and `:cnewer` to move through quickfix lists. See `:h quickfix-error-lists` for more information.

Comment: this is a good potential solution; however, I'm already using make to compile the whole program. If there is no other way, than I would have to bind <F5> to swap makeprg between total make and g++.

Comment: Using :make is definitely the best solution because of the quickfix feature. If make takes a long time when you've only changed one file, perhaps you could change your Makefile.

Comment: can some one post a link on how can I temporary change makeprg to g++ in the mapping of the key? should it be a function or is there one-line solution?

Comment: You don't want to change `&makeprg`. The default value is the right one, even for g++ as a compiler.

Comment: @kirill_igum In the most hackish and unrecommendable way possible, this actually works to flip `makeprg` between bare g++ and make:  `:map <F5> :set makeprg=g++\ %<CR>:make<CR>:set makeprg=make<CR>`   This could be improved by saving the current value of `makeprg` if it isn't just `make`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vim from the terminal just suspend vim with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

This will send you back to your terminal. You should see the commands that you just ran via `:!`. To get back to vim issue the `fg`. Note: This maybe different depending upon your shell.

Answer (score 1):

`:sh` starts you a shell within Vim. If you're using Vim in a terminal, this switches back to what's known as the "primary buffer", which means that you see the history from the terminal before you started Vim, as well as any of the `:!` commands you ran in Vim.
You can get back to your Vim session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Michael gave you the right answer: `:make`is the way to go. The old `:!compilation-command` is to be forgotten. Vi is, well, ... history.

Now to clarify : you'd almost never have to tweak `&makeprg`. The default value is the one you want to use, unless:

- you're using something else to compile (ant, ...)
- you want to compile a mono file program, and you don't want write a Makefile, and you're under mingw whose gnumake installation s*cks (all other installations of gnumake do permit to transform foo.c/cpp into foo(.exe) without having to write any single Makefile)
- you want to play with the compilation directory, or with things that can't be injected through $CXXFLAGS, $LDFLAGS, $CFLAGS, etc.

Comment: basically, I want to keep both options: make everything and g++ the current file (%) that I didn't include into total make yet. however now that I think about it's not that bad to just include it (easy in cmake). however, still there might be cases when I wouldn't want to change makefile. but I think the main problem is solved by changing the makefile. thanks

Comment: My way of doing it is the following: a directory is dedicated to tests where I do compile only the current file (into an executable), and a set of directories for the current project. In the tests directory, I have no Makefile. In the project directories I have either Makefiles, or cmakefiles, or sconfiles, or whatever the project uses.